# Making my own data type

Tags: java

I'm new to programming and Java. I'm trying to write my own data type/collection class but I'm not quite sure how to go about it.

I want a class that contains a string, and an array-list of strings.

Usually I would go about making a data type like this:

```
public class Collection {

    private int id;
    private String word;
    private int howMany;
    private char firstChar;

    public Collection (int i, String w, int h, char f){
        id = i;
        word = w;
        howMany = h;
        firstChar = f;
    }
//Getters and Setters
}
```

Not sure how I can do this with an ArrayList field.

My goal behind this is to have a class of unique words in the string field read in from .txt files and in the arraylist field have all the .txt file names that contain that word.

Edit: Building on Tom Anderson's Response and what I initially thought to do:

```
public class Collection {

    private int id;
    private String word;
    private int howMany;
    private char firstChar;
    private List<String> filenames;

    public Collection (int i, String w, int h, char f, List<String> filenames){
        id = i;
        word = w;
        howMany = h;
        firstChar = f;
        this.filenames = filenames;
    }

}
```

I'm still not sure how to use this since I can not simply add a string to the ArrayList parameter when creating a new instance of the my Collection Class. Such as this:

```
ArrayList<Collection> collection = new ArrayList<Collection>();
Collection newTest= new Collection("test","test");
collection.add(newTest);
```

Comment: if you are trying to implement a search/ index, you could leverage lucene. You could create your own collection by either extending an collection, or by encapsulating it.

Comment: What is that `Collection` constructor you're calling in your last snippet? You haven't shown a constructor that takes two strings before.

Answer (score 4):

Before i go on, `Collection` is not a good name for a class, because there is already a wildly popular class of that name in the `java.util` package. I'll call your class Occurrences.

To take your question at face value, it would be:

```
public class Occurrences {

    private int id;
    private String word;
    private int howMany;
    private char firstChar;
    private List<String> filenames;

    public Occurrences (int i, String w, int h, char f, List<String> filenames){
        id = i;
        word = w;
        howMany = h;
        firstChar = f;
        this.filenames = filenames;
    }

}
```

Had you considered that? What problems do you have with this?

There are a few things worth mentioning.

Firstly, you asked for an `ArrayList`, but the list of filenames has a couple of distinctive features: it can only contain each filename once, and the order of the filenames doesn't matter (i assume). That means that it is really a `Set`, not a `List`; the implementation class to use here would be `HashSet`.

Secondly, you still need to produce this collection of filenames, and perhaps this is where you're stumped. Are you reading this information in from a file? If so, let's say you have a comma-separated list of filenames in a string. Like:

```
String filenamesStr = "one.txt,two.txt,three.txt";
```

The simplest way of turning those into a set is to split them into an array, wrap the array in a list, and use the list to construct a set (yes, really!):

```
Set<String> filenames = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(filenamesStr.split(",")));
```

Alternatively, you may be building up the filenames as you process files. In that case, perhaps what you should do is let the Occurrences class accumulate them:

```
public class Occurrences {

    private int id;
    private String word;
    private int howMany;
    private char firstChar;
    private Set<String> filenames;

    public Occurrences (int i, String w){
        id = i;
        word = w;
        firstChar = w.charAt(0); // bonus feature!
        howMany = 0;
        filenames = new HashSet<String>();
    }

    public void addOccurrence(String filename) {
        ++howMany;
        filenames.add(filename);
    }

}
```

Then, as you index your files, simply call `addOccurrence` every time you see a word.

Thirdly, as other answerers have pointed out, a `Map` would be a good way to organise your whole universe of words. You can use the word as a key, and either an `Occurences` or a raw collection of filenames as the value, depending on what you really need.

Comment: This is exactly what I was thinking, but the reason I didn't think it would work is when creating a new instance of the class how would I just add a string into an arraylist. Simply doing this does not work. Collection newTest= new Collection("test","test");
   collection.add(newTest);

Comment: There is an old trick for this when you want to add some values to a Collection off the bat... Collection<String> newTest = new ArrayList<String>() {{ add("test"); add("test") }};

Comment: @jkschneider: Ah, the old Double-Brace Initializer. That seems a rather futile use of it, given the existence of `Arrays.asList`; however, it is certainly very useful for initialising maps.

Comment: @Tom: Remember that Arrays.asList returns an immutable list. He couldn't add anything else later...

Comment: @jkschneider: Very true. You usually need to feed that list straight into the constructor of some other collection.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do can be done through the use of a [HashMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html). An example of which can be obtained [here](http://www.roseindia.net/javatutorials/javahashmap.shtml).

You can do something like so:

```
Map<String, List<String>> myMap = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
```

Then, load the files and do what you need.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need your own datatype.  This is what the Map class is for:

```
public void someMethod() {
    Map<String, Collection<String>> filesByUniqueWord = new HashMap<String, Collection<String>>();

    // inserting new entries
    String uniqueWord = "hi";      
    List<String> filesContainingWord;  // assume you have this        
    filesByUniqueWord.put(uniqueWord, filesContainingWord);

    // deleting entries
    filesByUniqueWord.remove(uniqueWord);

    // getting all the files that contain some word
    List<String> retrieved = filesByUniqueWord.get("hi"); // retrieved == filesContainingWord
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all don't call the class Collection that will be very confusing since Collection exists as part of the java.util library.

Second, I am assuming you actually want to write a collection because you are learning how to do it, otherwise please use a HashMap or some other kind of map as described in some of the other answers.

So assuming you actually want to write the Collection yourself, I suggest implementing one of the standard java interfaces. Either [java.util.Collection](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) or [Iterable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html). This second one would be the easiest.

So something like

```
class MyCollection extends Iterable {

    private String yourString;
    private String theArray;
    public MyCollection(String yourString, String[] theArray) {
        this.yourString = yourString;
        this.theArray = theArray
    }

    public boolean hasNext() {
        // See if there is a next element to return
        ...
    }

    public String next() {
       // return the next one
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need is an ArrayList of String. Now by seeing your code I am assuming we will be using getters and setters. So when you are using setters I think its not the best practice to assign values to your varibales inside the constructor. Instead of that you can just instantiate your objects inside your constructor

```
public class Collection { 

private int id; 
private String word; 
private int howMany; 
private char firstChar;
private ArrayList<String> txtFiles; 

public Collection (int i, String w, int h, char f){ 
    word=new String();
    txtFiles=new ArrayList<String>();
  } 
}
```

Now for your ArrayList you can use the methods such as

```
Add(String file)
Remove(String file)
```

To add and remove file names

And for setting other variables use getters and setters like

```
setId(int id)
getId()
```

The other coding logic is upto you but I think thats how you should design your class